# Public/Private keys generated by SshKeyGenerator don't work

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I use this simple code

```
        int keySize = 2048;
        string publicKey, privateKey;

        var keygen = new SshKeyGenerator.SshKeyGenerator(keySize);

        publicKey = keygen.ToRfcPublicKey();
        privateKey = keygen.ToPrivateKey();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\id_rsa", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(privateKey);
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\authorized_keys", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(publicKey);
        }
```

And then try to connect to SSH server by using OpenSSH on Win10 like

```
ssh admin@localhost -i "C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\id_rsa"
```

And it doesn't work.

However, keys generated by simple 'ssh-keygen' in console work perfectly, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In VS you do not have Admin Priviledge unless you right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access `C:\Users\Admin` form VSCode, you could [get the `USEPROFILE` environment value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38252474/6309), and use that as your base folder for `.ssh`.

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
```

That way, VSCode launched as you (and not as admin) would work, provided you move your keys in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`.
It is better to not work as Admin anyway if possible (like it is better to not work as root on Linux).