# How can I get other user's folder path in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to get other users (let's say non-admin users) documents folder path when I am logged in as Admin

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

This is returning me the admin user folder path. But I want a nonadmin user's documents folder path.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337578/12031933

Comment: The main issue is that each user may redict most of those folders as they see fit. In fact you would find my Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures and some other folders anywhere but C:\Users. So retreiving this stuff from the Registery is about the only way. Note that elevation might be nessesary to access the paths or even the registery entries. | Also note that the Folder Names involving the User name do not change if the user is renamed.